# Rails: Form partial not clearing/reloading after AJAX submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am trying to create a one page/view application. I have a form I submit that creates a simple tweet object:

**_form.html.erb**

```
<div id="schedule-tweet-form">
  <%= simple_form_for @tweet, :remote => true do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :text, :input_html => {:cols => 60, :rows => 6} %>
    <%= f.input :scheduled_time %>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Schedule Tweet", :class => "f-button" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

(scheduled_time is a datetime type, has multiple select boxes)

The form submission works fine and creates a row in my database without a problem. The issue is that after it submits, the data in the form is not cleared. The text for the tweet is still in the input textbox and the scheduled time still has its respective select boxes chosen.

Here is my controller:

**tweets_controller.rb**

```
class TweetsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @tweet = Tweet.new
  end

  def create
    @tweet = Tweet.new(params[:tweet])
    @tweet.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @tweet.save
        @tweet.tweet_at_scheduled_time
        flash[:notice] = "Tweet has been scheduled"
        format.html { render 'index' }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render 'index' }
        format.js { render 'reload' }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the view where the partial is rendered:

**index.html.erb**

```
<div id="schedule-tweet-form-container">
  <%= render 'form' %>
</div>
```

I tried to use some jQuery to remove the form and re-render a new one once the form is submitted and the create action is called, but weirdly the form comes back with the submitted tweet's information after "append" is called (text & scheduled_time data in the input fields).

**create.js.erb**

```
<% if @tweet.save %>
  $("#schedule-tweet-form").remove();
  $('#schedule-tweet-form-container').append("<%= j render 'form' %>");
<% end %>
```

I have been racking my brain on this the past couple of hours and nothing else I tried from various other stack overflow questions has worked. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your create action, after saving the tweet, you need to initialize the Tweet object again.

But in your create.js.erb you have used the @tweet, so modify the code as following

```
<% if @tweet.save 
     @tweet = Tweet.new
%>

  $("#schedule-tweet-form").remove();
  $('#schedule-tweet-form-container').append("<%= j render 'form' %>");
<% end %>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. It ended up throwing me an undefined method error. Plus, shouldn't it trigger `@tweet = Tweet.new` when it  again hits the index action?

Comment: That did it, thanks a lot. I also had it working when I changed `render 'index'` to `redirect_to`, added a respond_to block to the `index` action and the jQuery code to `index.js.erb` but it was refreshing the page, I'm guessing because of the redirect. Your solution is completely AJAX-y though and keeps it all on one page with no refresh. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

you should use

```
    format.json
```

on ajax calls

check the following answer of this thread to make simple form make a json post

[Is there a way to submit ajax/json requests with simple_form for Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255198/is-there-a-way-to-submit-ajax-json-requests-with-simple-form-for-rails)

Comment: I don't know a whole lot about JSON yet, it is still kind of confusing to me. Any good resources on where I can learn more about it?

Comment: rendering js on ajax calls is a practice that has been discouraged. instead handle response of your POST / PUT calls and do the needful on the client side. If any data needs to be transferred from client side to server or vice versa. use JSON as serialization format. javascript vatively understands JSON and Rails has builtin support to serialize/deserialize json

Comment: @irfn, I'm interested in this too, and was hoping you might be able to direct me towards any decent articles that expand more on the advantages of rendering json instead of js